# (Android 2.1) "onContextItemSelected" and "window already focused, ignoring focus <snap irrelavant rest>"

Tags: java, android

I encounter this strange problem. I have followed the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu exactly. I already tested it on separate dummy application and it worked fine. The problem is "Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@xxxxxx" whenever I tried to click any context menu item after pressing-and-holding any list item. "onContextItemSelected" method is never called at all time.

Here're the condensed codes:

---

**TaskActivity.java**

```
public class TaskActivity extends Activity{
    private ListView task_list;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);//custom xml file of my GUI

        task_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTasks);

        populateTaskList();//snapped method
        registerForContextMenu(task_list);

     }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        Log.v("CBC","HERE2");//It logs, yes

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.v("CBC","HERE1");//Not ever logged this message!
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit_menuitem:
                update_task(info.id);
                return true;
            case R.id.delete_menuitem:
                Log.v("CBC","HERE2");
                delete_task(info.id);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }
}

<snap irrelevant codes that have played no role in this problem>
```

**activity_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <snap irrelvant codes>
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selectors"
        android:id="@+id/listTasks"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**task_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dip"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/mark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

So I am wondering if you have known anything about this such strange problem? Let me know if you need to know more codes else. I assure you they are not relevant.

P.S. This is my big first application written.
P.S.S. I just write this little application for my special needs on my Android phone. (Android market free ones are unsuitable to me).

Answer (score 0):

this explains why you cant use onMenuItemSelectedmethod and onContextItemSelected together..

http://biginteger.blogspot.com/2010/09/solution-to-oncontextitemselected-not.html